# Creating an Exchange Mailbox for a User in C#

Tags: c#, email, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I just created a user in Active Directory. I would like to create an exchange mailbox for this user. Can I just set some of the users properties? Something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry user = ...Get the user
user.Properties["someProerty"] = "someValue";
user.CommitChanges();
```

Where `someProperty` and `someValue` are what is needed to create a mailbox?

Is there documentation on how to do this? Could you tell me what properties need set?

Answer (score 3):

No, an exchange mailbox is more than just properties on an LDAP entry. You'll actually need to work with Exchange directly to accomplish this. If you are using Exchange 2007+ you can use the [New-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663.aspx) PowerShell commandlet.

In one of my previous jobs, I installed the Exchange Management Tools on my web server and automated creating a PowerShell runtime environment to execute the necessary commandlets. Once you execute the right commands the attributes (such as mailbox, email, etc.) will be added by Exchange.

You can create a PowerShell runtime environment by creating a [runspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacefactory%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313114 perhaps.
There is tons of documentation on these things, try google ;)

For 2007 exchange try this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/4cd5ea2e-5967-42f2-a503-f1e031a1b393/

Comment: Thank You for your comment. I tried that link, but it appears CDOEXM.dll can only be used against a 2000 or 2003 Exchange server it wont work against a 2007 server. This is one of the dependencies of that soultion

Comment: Thats too bad, check my updated answer with additional solution for 2007 exchange

Answer (score 0):

No You have to use powershell cmdlet to change some properties of mailBox .For Example You can not change Alias Name with the help of Active Directory Cmdlets.I am also new and this is just my experience.hope this will be helpfull to you.